# Paypal option is not showing in the Merchant hosted page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, paypal

Can someone help me to find out why Payment with Paypal option is not showing in Merchant hosted page?

I searched and found that enabling "Express payment option" will solve the problem but in my Paypal manager console i did't see any option like this "Express payment option".

Can somebody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need to enable Express Checkout and configure it in your application / shopping cart.

Comment: Yes, for express checkout, Paypal option will be displayed but why this is not displaying in Merchant hosted page? Actually i want to enable it in merchant hosted page. By the way thanks for your help :)

Comment: In the Manager, on your Service Settings > Set Up page, do you have your PayPal email address entered in the field labeled same?

Comment: I recommend calling into PayPal Support. It may be an account setting that will need to be turned on by a PayPal Support Rep.